# Using Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter query help required

Tags: apache, expression, jmeter, correlation, loadrunner

```
"id": [ 
    "2022342452345345559093" 
  ]
```

---

Regular Expression:---->`"id":([^,]+)"`

I am getting id but along with some values

```
refer value= =%5B%222022342452345345559093
```

I am getting some other value i.e `{%5B%22}`

I tried many ways but there is no luck. Please help me in this.

Note: Space is there and new line also is there, because of that only I am getting some other value, any help in this.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using Regular Expressions to extract data from JSON. There is a [JMeter Plugin](http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/) (you'll need Extras with Libs Set) which enables JSONPath Extractor in JMeter. See [Using XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) (scroll down to `Parsing JSON`) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Dmitri T is correct, the JSON extractor will be much more solid.

If you do want to use the regex approach, The value you are getting at the start of you is actually URL encoded values. You can use a URL Decoder like this [one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) to find this stuff out.

```
%5B = [
%22 = "
```

This is because your regular expression is setup to capture anything after the : as [ is a [special character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) in regex.

You can use the following regex if you prefer

```
id":[^,"]+"(\d+)"
```